# Highcharts IE10 support

Tags: rendering, highcharts, internet-explorer-10, imagedownload

I am using highcharts and am having issues with the functionality with internet explorer 10.01.

For polar charts the series do not load until you roll the mouse over the chart. If you have a series that is an area (filled), you need to turn the series off then on again before it displays.(version 2.3.5 does not fix this issue)

Saving the presented image from the icon with the chart does not render correctly. You can it is a radar chart, but cannot make out any of the values, or colours. They tend to be grey. (version 2.3.5 fixes this issue)

Are these issues known?

Is there a solution to these issues/work around? Has it something to do with SVG? Could I force it to use VML?

Is there a planned fix for these?

Comment: which version u r using?

Answer (score 1):

This is now a recognised as an issue by highcharts and it will be fixed in due course

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1499

Update:
A hack workaround in the meantime, is to hide and show a single series on the chart after you have rendered in, in JavaScript

```
    if(chart.series.length>0)
    {
        chart.series[0].hide();
        chart.series[0].show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Version 2.3.5 it has fixed IE10 support.

Comment: The download new image works in the new version, but the chart series do not appear when loaded. You need to roll over with it with your mouse or unload and reload the series for it to appear.

Comment: Have you any example of it ?

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan, it is not working off the demo highcharts have made available, with this specific version of the browser: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

Comment: @monymirza this example is not polar chart

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar/

Comment: The Series on this polar chart do not appear for me without turning the series on or off, or I roll over the chart itself.

Comment: I had same problem and upgrading to v3.0.9 (2014-01-15) solved my issue.